# how many YN-622C do you need to work with YN-568EX II

Tags: off-camera-flash

I'm interested in buying a Yongnuo 568EX II flash for my Canon 550D, and use it off-camera.

I understand I have to attach a wireless trigger (YN-622C) to my camera, but I'm not sure whether the 568EX II will also need to be connected to a receiver or this is built in?

Hope it makes sense!

Thanks,
P.

Comment: The YN-568EX II functions just like a Canon master/slave flash unit. You don't need a YN-622C at all to trigger it optically with another Canon compatible flash capable of operating as a master. If you want to trigger it via radio signal you will need both a transmitter and receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Apparently the review I found was simply 100% incorrect or perhaps it was for the first version and I missed it.  As Michael Clark was kind enough to point out, it appears that the YN-622C does in fact have wireless optical sync master capability though it does not have radio sync.  You only need two of the YN-622Cs if you want to radio trigger.

Comment: Au contraire mon fraire. The 568EX II does have wireless *optical* sync, including E-TTL, built in. It would, of course need an optical trigger such as (possibly the built in flash or) a camera mounted master such as the 580EX II or the 600EX-RT to enable E-TTL. The Yn-568EXII will also function as an optical master in Canon's or Nikon's current TTL systems. Any other flash should trigger it optically in manual mode. I think what you meant to say was the YN-568EX II has no radio receiver built in.

Comment: @MichaelClark - Wow, I must have found bad information.  My research yesterday had a review that said it didn't support Canon's optical sync or even have one at all, but I see now from some more research that no only do they have it, but it can even be a flash master for a Canon based system.  I shall alter my answer, sorry about that.  Too bad I don't remember the site so that I can avoid using it again.

Comment: Thanks guys - does my 550D have the ability to trigger the off camera flash optically then? If so, what is the difference between using this setup and the one with radio transceivers (beside more flexibility in positioning the off camera flash)?

Comment: @Patrick - since it says it is compatible with Canon's optical sync, if you have optical master built in to the camera, it should be able to drive the system.  You are correct about the primary difference about the radio triggering, though the exact capabilities of each radio trigger system can differ a bit.  For example, Canon's official system gives more groups to work with, but cheaper radio options may not allow as much in the way of groups.  The best bet is to look at the specs on the particular radio system.

Answer (score 0):

You need two YN-622C triggers; the YN-568EXII does not have a radio receiver built into it.  It does have an optical sensor and *can* be used as both a Canon optical master or slave; as well as a "dumb" optical slave with any flash burst setting it off.

However, Canon only put a master into the pop-up flash of the dRebel line with the 600D and later models, so to use this system, you'd need another master unit on the camera hotshoe (e.g., a 90EX, ST-E2, 580EXII or 600-EX-RT) if you wanted to use the flash wirelessly with TTL function, which is likely to cost more than a pair of YN-622C triggers.

The YN-568EXII also has the S1/S2 "dumb" optical slave modes that can be used with the 550D's pop-up flash (or any flash for that matter) set to Manual (S1) or eTTL (S2).